# In PHP 5 can I instantiate a class dynamically?

Tags: php, class, dynamic, instantiation

Is it possible to dynamically instantiate a class using a variable? For example is something like this possible in PHP?

```
class foo
{
    public $something;
}

$class_name = "foo";

$f = new $class_name();
```

Comment: I disagree that this is not a real question. First of all it is grammatically a real question, secondly it has a definite answer with  possibility of elaboration, thirdly it is easy to tell what is being asked, which is demonstrated by that fact that all the answers are essentially the same. While it is true that this, my first question on SO, was somewhat  of a blunder, still to those who aren't able to randomly guess the correct syntax on their first try will benefit from a clear and searchable post on the subject.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

That should work, yes.

You can also do:

```
$f = new $class($arg1,$arg2);
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, this code will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

> In PHP 5 can I instantiate a class
>   dynamically?

***Yes*** you can, your code should work fine.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course you can instantiate using dynamic names;