# How to use variable name to call a class?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to use a variable (string value) to call a Class. Can I do it ? I search for PHP ReflectionClass but I do not know how to use a method from Reflection Result. Like this:

```
    foreach($menuTypes as $key => $type){
        if($key != 'Link'){
            $class = new \ReflectionClass('\App\Models\\' . $key);

            //Now $class is a ReflectionClass Object
            //Example: $key now is "Product"
            //I'm fail here and cannot call the method get() of 
            //the class Product

            $data[strtolower($key) . '._items'] = $class->get();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean saying to call a class? Do you want to create a class instance?

Comment: @IhorBurlachenko create instalce(call class constructor)

Comment: It looks like you don't need reflection. If you want to instantiate an object, you can do `$object = new $key();`

Comment: @jeroen & Ihor Burlachenko: this is exactly what I want. So simple, Thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In PHP 5 can I instantiate a class dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3112727/in-php-5-can-i-instantiate-a-class-dynamically)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without ReflectionClass:

```
$instance = new $className();
```

With ReflectionClass: use the [`ReflectionClass::newInstance()` method](http://php.net/reflectionclass.newinstance):

```
$instance = (new \ReflectionClass($className))->newInstance();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found one like this

```
$str = "ClassName";
$class = $str;
$object = new $class();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use directly like below

```
$class = new $key();

$data[strtolower($key) . '._items'] = $class->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

The risk is that the class doesn't exist. So it's better to check before instantiating.

### With php's class_exists method

Php has a built-in method to check if the class exists.

```
$className = 'Foo';
if (!class_exists($className)) {
    throw new Exception('Class does not exist');
}

$foo = new $className;
```

### With try/catch with rethrow

A nice approach is trying and catching if it goes wrong.

```
$className = 'Foo';

try {
    $foo = new $className;
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    throw new MyClassNotFoundException($e);
}

$foo->bar();
```

Comment: Yes, you can with try/catch. Try to instantiate > class doesn't exist > exception > class not found